# "Add Service Reference..." to xsd

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, service-reference

I can create a service reference in Visual Studio 2010 to an xsd. That reference downloads all the linked xsd files. However, I have 2 problems I'd like to see if there are solutions:

- The URL for each xsd actually ends in .gx (e.g., http://mycompany.com/Schema1.gx). When Visual Studio imports the files, it renames them to .xsd, but in the xsd:import node, it keeps the original reference name with .gx, so my reference, once it's in Visual Studio is "not found or invalid"
- for some of the xsd:import statements, the path to the referred-to .gx file is in another directory (e.g., schemaLocation="subDirectory1/Schema1.gx"). However, when they're imported, all xsd files are in the same directory in Visual Studio, but again, the xsd:import node is not modified to reflect the flatter structure.

Is there a solution to import these xsds in a valid way?

Comment: Certainly sounds very strange. Have you tried using svcutil on it's own? You can then bring only the generated code into visual studio, which will enable you to make the service call, but leave the schemas out.

Comment: Actually, it's the schemas I'm interested in, not the service call. The service call is a legacy call that takes a string parameter, which is an xml doc conforming to the xsd's I'm trying to download.

Comment: In your original question it sounds as if your service reference generation was successful except for the schemas. Does this actually mean that the service reference generation did not generate the contract types?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a bug - the svcutil doesn't "refactor" the schemas. If you want a tool that handles this kind of work and more like it, [this](http://paschidev.com) XML Schema refactoring tool should help. Download, install and create a new XML Schema Refactoring file (.xsr); add a new XML Schema collection; right click on the version 1.0, select [Import Schema Files...] command and follow the prompts. It can "slurp" online schemas, including ones referenced from, or embedded into, WSDL files, etc.