# How to Add Service Reference to xsd file

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am using VS 2010 to develop an app which consumes a web service created by a team of Oracle developers. Their service is still in development so I asked for a wsdl file as soon as their interface design was complete (so I could create my proxy classes and get started).

What I received was a zip file named 'WSDL' full of XML and XSD files. They believe they have satisfied my request but I'm stumped as to what to do with these files. Visual Studio does not recognize them as service references, like it would a WSDL file.  Google hasn't been much help.

There is [a thread here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678945/add-service-reference-to-xsd) which suggests a service reference can be created with just an XSD, but does not elaborate on the steps required.

Do I really need a wsdl file (as I think I do) or am I just not clever enough to use what I've been given (be nice, now)?  Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use [`wsdl.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.71%29.aspx) to "generates code for XML Web services and XML Web service clients from [among others] XSD schemas."

I think you can then use [`svcutil.exe` to convert the .wsdl file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx) into an Interface you can use.

Comment: As I read the tool description, wsdl.exe will convert my XSD files into a proxy class not a wsdl file.  That's fine, I could work with that!  However, the tool outputs only a warning ('no classes were generated') and an empty interface class (output.cs). Same result for all the XSD files I tried.

Comment: After some analysis, it appears the XML documents provided to me contain WSDL document definitions (e.g. <wsdl:definitions name="name"?>).  I changed the file extensions from .xml to .wsdl, opened the files to correct invalid paths to the XSD schemas, saved, and am now able to add the wsdl files as service references to my project.

Comment: Yes, I ran the utility from the VS .NET Command Prompt. Thanks for your help.